# How to keep two repositories at two different locations in sync to serve as remotes

Tags: git, synchronization, githooks, git-push, git-remote

I have a situation.

I have two teams working on a project from two geographically distant locations.
The structure I have thought of is there will be two servers one at each location.
Developers at Location-A can push to server-A and same with B.

Now if developers at A have to push to  server-A, what should typically happen is Server-A should pull from Server-B, and then developer can push to Server-A after resolving any merge conflicts if any.

I have two questions here:
1. How do I achieve this?
2. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Seriously consider just using a private git repository at Github.

Or set up a single origin server at location A, and set up a VPN to access this server from location B. Then have all the developers push and submit pull requests to this single origin server.

Comment: GitHub out of equation. :)